# Swift error trying to find document in firebase by id using CODABLE class

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find a document using its id and store in a custom data class. So far, I've created my first function to search in Firebase a user by email. Email is the Id of the document. I've created a class as well to store the the user. You can see both codes here:
My firebase database:
[image]
My class:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift


    class Usuario: Codable {
    @DocumentID var email: String?
    let nombre: String
    let apellidos: String
    let telefono: String
    let contraseña: String
    let fotoPerfil: String?
    let ciudad: String
    
        init ( nombre: String, apellidos: String, usuario: String, contraseña: String, fotoPerfil: String?, ciudad: String){
            self.nombre = nombre
            self.apellidos = apellidos
            self.telefono = usuario
            self.contraseña = contraseña
            self.fotoPerfil = nil
            self.ciudad = ciudad
    }
```

My function:

```
private func buscarUsuarioPorEmail( documentId: String) {
  let docRef = db.collection("Usuarios").document("lorenzorubiorivera@hotmail.com")
  print("This is a quick check for debugging:  \(documentId)")
  docRef.getDocument(as: Usuario.self) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let usuario):
      self.usuarioActual = usuario
        print("El usuario actual es: \(self.usuarioActual.nombre) ")
        print(result)
    case .failure(let error):
      print("ERROR ENCONTRADO USUARIO \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

My main view:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseFirestore
import Lottie

class InicioViewController: UIViewController {
    // He utilizado una variable tipo lazy para poder inicializarla más tarde cuando se llama a la base datos
    lazy var usuarioActual = Usuario()
    lazy var usersCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Usuarios")
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmailUsuario: UITextView!
    // Creamos una conexión a Firestore
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    lazy var collectioRef = db.collection("Usuarios")
    
    // MARK: -- Recupero el email mediante su clave en UserDefaults
    private let email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "emailAutentificado")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Datos usuario actual"
        txtEmailUsuario.text = email
        buscarUsuarioPorEmail(documentId: email!)
}
```

I'm allways reciving the same console error:

> This is a quick check for debugging:  lorenzorubiorivera@hotmail.com
> ERROR ENCONTRADO USUARIO The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Comment: Replace `error.localizedDescription` with `error`. It show you the real error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I think the issue could be this variables in your decodable:

```swift
let contraseña: String
```

Translated It looks like this means `password` so if you make this nullable, or just remove it, see if it starts working as your document does not contain a value for a key of password.

Comment: Yes....you were right...My mistakes I forgot that you don't need to store the password as firebase uses it own autentifcation section. You're a genius! Thanks!!

Comment: by the way? How could I get ALL my Events from the same data base in a similar way?